# How do I fix these BSODs?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have windows 7 ultimate running on an Acer Aspire 7560 with 4gb of ram, and an AMD A6 or A8 processor, I believe. I've been getting these BSODs recently and I'm wondering what they point to. I used Nirsoft BlueScreenViewer to get this info instead of uploading the individual files, and they can be found here: http://pastebin.com/2PkNw9Mz

I understand this isn't a ton of info but I want a few people to advise me before I go digging around deep within my system for some elusive fix and doing damage on my way. I'd like a fix with as little third party programs as possible (as few that I've never heard of that is.)
Thanks in advance for your help!

What I've already tried:
*memtest (ran for an hour with no error)
*I'm currently running an SFC /SCANNOW
*hotfixes for a couple of them from M$, they said they didn't apply to my computer
Edit: the scannow finished and gave me this:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of th
em.
Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log

The system file repair changes will take effect after the next reboot.

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: I'm going to reboot and see if it changed anything. I'll run my computer for a few hours without suspend or hibernate and see if anything happens

Comment: could it at all have been caused by a UXtheme patch I applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To ascertain precisely *what* sfc found...**

- Open an elevated command prompt...
  Open the Start Menu, click on All Programs and Accessories, right click on Command Prompt, and click on Run as administrator.
- At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
  findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
- Open the sfcdetails file that appears on the desktop

  Note: The Sfcdetails.txt file contains details from every time that the System File Checker tool has been run on the computer. The file includes information about files that were not repaired by the System File Checker tool.
  Verify the date and time entries to determine the problem files that were found the last time that you ran the System File Checker tool.

Comment: I looked through the file and found that a couple of the files from the kernel had been modified, seemingly by some virus or just by mistake by the theme patcher. I ran a malwarebytes scan and it showed the theme patcher in my downloads folder as a trojan. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome. Glad you got it :-)